# Trying to run ufraw-batch in QProcess on macOS does not work

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, qprocess

I currently try to extract the embedded images of some RAW images (.CR2) so I can display them as JPG in Qt. With the following code:

```
QProcess ufraw;
ufraw.start("/bin/sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "ufraw-batch /Users/dublin/Pictures/Ich/IMG_5098.CR2 --embedded-image");
ufraw.waitForFinished(-1);
```

I try to run `ufraw-batch`. But this does not work even if I use `startDetached()`. There is no result (should be a file ending on `.embedded.jpg`). Any other way to do this or what am I doing wrong here?

Whats also really interesting is that if I run `ufraw-batch /Users/dublin/Pictures/Ich/IMG_5098.CR2 --embedded-image`  from normal terminal everything works fine.

I am currently on macOS Catalina.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting so with a lot of research I tried directly running the `ufraw-batch` executable from `/usr/local/bin` and actually this worked.

So

```
QProcess ufraw;
ufraw.start("/usr/local/bin/ufraw-batch MY_FILE.CR2 --embedded-image");
```

just works!